# FSM question from HDLBits has different output than expected

Tags: verilog

Question:-
Consider a finite state machine that is used to control some type of motor. The FSM has inputs x and y, which come from the motor, and produces outputs f and g, which control the motor. There is also a clock input called clk and a reset input called resetn.

The FSM has to work as follows. As long as the reset input is asserted, the FSM stays in a beginning state, called state A. When the reset signal is de-asserted, then after the next clock edge the FSM has to set the output f to 1 for one clock cycle. Then, the FSM has to monitor the x input. When x has produced the values 1, 0, 1 in three successive clock cycles, then g should be set to 1 on the following clock cycle. While maintaining g = 1 the FSM has to monitor the y input. If y has the value 1 within at most two clock cycles, then the FSM should maintain g = 1 permanently (that is, until reset). But if y does not become 1 within two clock cycles, then the FSM should set g = 0 permanently (until reset).

(The original exam question asked for a state diagram only. But here, implement the FSM.)

My Code:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input resetn,    // active-low synchronous reset
    input x,
    input y,
    output f,
    output g
); 
    parameter a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3,e=4,f1=5,g1=6,h=7,i=8,per=9;
    reg [3:0] state,ns;
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(~resetn)
            ns<=a;
        case(state)
            a:ns<=resetn ? b : a;
            b:ns<=c;
            c:ns<=x ? d : c;
            d:ns<=x ? d : e;
            e:ns<=x ? f1 : d;
            f1:ns<=y ? per : g1;
            g1:ns<=y ? per : i;
            per:ns<=resetn ? per : a;
            i:ns<=resetn ? i : a;
        endcase
    end
    assign state=ns;
    assign f=(state==b);
    assign g=(state==f1|state==g1|state==per);
endmodule
```

[image: Timing Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your reset logic.  You should separate the reset clause from the rest of your logic; it should only be included in the `if` clause, and it should not be in the `case` statement.

Also, the `case` statement should be in an `else` clause:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input resetn,    // active-low synchronous reset
    input x,
    input y,
    output f,
    output g
); 
    parameter a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3,e=4,f1=5,g1=6,h=7,i=8,per=9;
    reg [3:0] state;
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (~resetn) begin
            state<=a;
        end else begin
            case(state)
                a:state<=b;
                b:state<=c;
                c:state<=x ? d : c;
                d:state<=x ? d : e;
                e:state<=x ? f1 : d;
                f1:state<=y ? per : g1;
                g1:state<=y ? per : i;
            endcase
        end
    end
    assign f=(state==b);
    assign g=(state==f1|state==g1|state==per);
endmodule
```

There is no need to have 2 state variables.  I changed the FSM so that it only keeps `state`.